# Creating new edges in networkx undirected graph

Tags: python, networkx

I have an undirected graph with edge weights either `1` or `0`. Following is the code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_edge('a', 'b', weight=1)
G.add_edge('a', 'c', weight=0)
G.add_edge('c', 'd', weight=1)
G.add_edge('c', 'e', weight=1)
G.add_edge('c', 'f', weight=1)

elarge = [(u, v) for (u, v, d) in G.edges(data=True) if d['weight'] == 1]
esmall = [(u, v) for (u, v, d) in G.edges(data=True) if d['weight'] == 0]

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)  # positions for all nodes

# nodes
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=700)

# edges
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=elarge,
                       width=6)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=esmall,
                       width=6, alpha=0.5, edge_color='b', style='dashed')

# labels
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size=20, font_family='sans-serif')

plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

This generates following graph.

[image: Sample Graph]

Now I want to:

1. Detect all connected components with edge weights `1` (which are two in this case).
2. If there exists a `0` edge between connected component A and connected component B (dashed line in this case), create new edges between all the nodes of connected component A and all nodes of connected component B with edge weight `0`. Do nothing otherwise.

I have been trying to do it using loops but my program crashes as I have 10 million nodes in graph and 0.25 million connected components. Is there a faster way to do it either using `networkx` or any other library?

### Edit

Program crashes after 4 days and gives out of memory error.

Comment: As an alternative to `networkx` I highly recommend using neo4j if you are looking at doing analytics on large graph datasets

Comment: It might help to know which place your program crashes at

Comment: What is the purpose of adding new edges between every node of A and every node of B? It would create a huge graph with redundant information. There could be a way to avoid this, depending on the problem.

Comment: @ducminh That's a really good point. Perhaps the issue is that too many edges are being built in the graph resulting in it crashing?

Comment: I can't imagine why you would need to do this.  There won't be a fast way to do it, and memory requirements will be huge.  You can maybe make it less slow somehow.  But - can you explain why you need to do this?

Comment: Actually edge weights denote the relationship between nodes. 1 means nodes are related, 0 means they are not related. So if one connected component is collection of related nodes and there exist a single non related edge with a second connected component (which is also collection of related nodes), it means all nodes of first CC are not related to second CC. I want to generate all these new connections and are required for my research analysis on the graph.

Comment: Wouldn't it be much simpler if nodes are related iff there is an edge connecting them? If two nodes are not related, no edge needs to be added at all.

Comment: @ducminh yeah it would. But I need those newly generated pairs. It's part of analysis to see how many new pairs we can come up with.

Comment: If all you need is to count the number of newly generated pairs, we can just count them: |A| × |B|, then subtract the number of existing "unrelated pairs".

Comment: @ducminh no I need those pairs as well.... There is a long list of analysis that is dependent on these newly generated pairs.

Comment: @SalA. You can always check if a pair is "newly generated" or not: u, v belong to two different components, and (u, v) is not an existing edge of weight 0. Could you try to count (or estimate) the number of newly generated pairs? If this number is too large, it's not reasonable at all to create all of them.

Comment: Let's be clear - you're talking about a network with 10^14 or so edges.  Each with a weight associated with it.  If the computer spends even 10^-7 seconds to process each edge, you're talking about months of CPU time.  Almost certainly the right answer is to figure out how to do your analysis without calculating all these edges.  If it is absolutely necessary, you need to use something other than python with parallel computation, and have immense patience as well as a fast CPU and lots of memory.

Comment: @Joel thanks for the answer. Ya it makes sense to think a clever algorithm based on the objective! I will think on those lines.